# Uploading file from local file system in node giving 400 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload a file to an API using multipart/form-data.

I am able to successfully do this using insomnia as follows:

[image]

Headers are set to Content-Type multipart/form-data and the basic auth is also set.

When I try to replicate this in my code I receive a 400 error.

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
const URL = 'https://api.app.uploadplace.com/v1/';
const token = 'randomkey';

async function readFile(path: string) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(path, 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }

      resolve(data);
    });
  });
}

export const Upload = async (path: string) => {

  const FormData = require('form-data');
  const form = new FormData();

  let file = await readFile(path);

  form.append('file', file);

  const config = {
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    auth: {
      username: token,
      password: ''
    }
  }

  await axios.post(URL, form, config).then(() => {
    console.log('success')
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  })
};
```

Comment: Just an FYI, there's a promisified version of `readFile`... https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesreadfilepath-options

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are appending the file contents as a string to your form data.

Instead, append the file readable stream...

```js
form.append("file", fs.createReadStream(path));

const config = {
  headers: form.getHeaders() // this includes correct mime boundary tokens
  auth: {
    username: token,
    password: ''
  }
}
```

See https://github.com/axios/axios#form-data